# How to transfer numbers in a panda series to an integer or float?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and jupyter notebook.

I want to tansfer(or extract) numbers in a panda series.

for example I have a panda series x

```
x=pd.Series(15)
print(x)
type(x)

0    15
dtype: int64
pandas.core.series.Series
```

and I want only the number 15 as an integer

```
x=15
print(x)
type(x)

15
int
```

how to transfer the panda series to a single number?

Comment: index it like `x[0]`

Comment: Try `pd.Series(15)[0]`

Comment: If you only have _one_ item, use `.item()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to print the numbers of the series, then you can do:

```
x = pd.Series(15)
print(x.values)
print(x.dtype)
```

The output is

```
[15]
int64
```

Comment: thanks, thats helpful. And what should I do if I just want part value of the series?           for example x = pd.Series([15,17])  and I want only the number 15?

Comment: you can do print(x.values[0]) to only get 15.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.values` property:

```
x=[3,5,7]
s=pd.Series(x)
s.values

Out[]: array([3, 5, 7], dtype=int64)
```

It will return values of the `Series` as `numpy` array.